# Sublime - how to strip extension in build file?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

I have the following build file for scss:

```
{
    "cmd": ["C:/bin/ruby193/bin/ruby.exe", "C:/bin/ruby193/bin/sass", "$file", "$file.css", "--precision", "5"],
    "selector": "source.scss"
}
```

Which works great for people who like building sass in sublime and outputs files of the format Home.scss.css.  Some of our team however uses visual studio's mindscape workbench for compilation, which from a recent update doesn't honor custom conventions and always outputs Home.css.

How do I adjust my sublime build file so that it strips the extension and always outputs Home.css?

I've tried `"$file".strip('.scss')` but I guess the file isn't interpreted using the full python interpreter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/build_systems.html

What you're searching for is `$file_path\$file_base_name.css` (or `/`).